# Creating alert combining indicator criteria for tradingview

Tags: pine-script, alert, trading, tradingview-api, indicator

I would like to get the following alerts:

1. buy alert when both the fisher line and trigger line oscillate below zero AND the fisher line crossover the trigger line.
2. Sell alert when when both the fisher line and trigger line oscillate above zero AND the trigger line crossover the fisher line.

I tried getting chatgpt to create the code but keep getting errors. Also, unsure if I put code into pinescript will i automatically get the alerts?